# Is there any way to create a custom UI for android Settings.Panel.ACTION_WIFI

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, wifimanager

I was trying to use the wifi on/off option. I came through Settings.Panel.ACTION_WIFI and it is working as expected. However the system UI has issues in some of the devices. It is getting distorted in tablets. Now I'm trying to fix this UI to the center of the device. Is there any option to override the default system window and place this dialog to the center of device ? The code I used is
Intent wifiIntent = new Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_WIFI);
startActivity(wifiIntent);

[image]